# Session text truncated when printed on form field

Tags: php, html, session

I stored a value from a form field eq "Olaleye Street, Ikosi" into a session variable. Whenever i want to edit the details, from the previous form, it only shows "Olaleye". Can somebody help me. `urlencode ( $_SESSION['address'] )` complicates the issue, pls help here is the code:

```
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" autocomplete="off" tabindex="3" class="txtinput"
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['address'])) {
        echo "value=" . $_SESSION['address'];
    }else {
        if($_SESSION['err']==true) {
            echo "style=\"border-color:#F00\"";
        }
    }
    ?>
>
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" autocomplete="off" tabindex="3" class="txtinput" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['address'])){ echo "value=".urlencode($_SESSION['address']);}else{if($_SESSION['err']==true){echo "style=\"border-color:#F00\"";}}?>>

Comment: You must add quotes that'll appear in the final output around the value of the `value` property. Like `echo "value=\"" . $_SESSION['address'] . "\"";`

Comment: @Gant is right. Try this: `echo 'value="' . $_SESSION['address'] . '"';`

Comment: Thanks all. Completing the quotes solved the problem.

Comment: I used echo "value=\"".$_SESSION['address']."\""; ad it worked fine.

Comment: @user1675600... You should add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Completing the quotes solved the problem for me.
I used:

echo "value=\"".$_SESSION['address']."\""; and it worked fine.